# Is it allowed to have multiple accounts on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, user-accounts

Does YouTube allow users to have multiple accounts? Do they specifically allow/forbid this practice?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a legal issue.

Comment: Web Applications is not intended for that? I didn't know. Advice me where to post questions like this one? @AlE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As youtube accounts are today google accounts you are more than welcome to have separate accounts for different stuff if you like. The legality however would depend on some factors:

1. Are you in a country that would restrict this in its laws and Google must abide by these laws?
2. Does the Terms of Service from Google allow you to have multiple accounts.

The #1 is impossible to answer as that may require us to know the jurisdiction you are under and so on, you better research this if needed yourself.

The #2 is pretty clear. Yes, you are allowed to have multiple google accounts under the Google Terms of Service (http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/) and therefore also tied to different Youtube accounts.

The terms of service says that the restriction is that you are not allowed to create multipåle accounts for

- Spoofing
- Spamming
- Scamming other users

Et cetera. Have a read through Google Terms of Service, it's not that long and it is actually rather  clear.

Here is proof from google support https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/179235?hl=en

Comment: Making a bot that will create YouTube accounts and then like videos is spoofing?